# When on a 50 meters radius around a marker, trigger method

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

What I need to do, is when the "user" marker gets into (let's say 50 meters radius) the radius of one of the place of interest marker popus an dialog ( showplaceDialog() ).

How can I do it? I have simply no clue of how to do it...

This is how I put the "user" marker, which moves as location changes.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d("Location", "onLocationChanged with location " + location.toString());

    if(overlayMarkerYou == null) {
        overlayMarkerYou = new MyOverlay(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_you),mapView);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(overlayMarkerYou);
    }else{
        mapView.getOverlays().remove(overlayMarkerYou);
        mapView.invalidate();
        overlayMarkerYou = new MyOverlay(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_you),mapView);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(overlayMarkerYou);
    }

    if (location != null) {

        mapView.invalidate();
        GeoPoint gpt = new GeoPoint(microdegrees(location.getLatitude()),microdegrees(location.getLongitude()));
        mapController.setCenter(gpt);
        overlayMarkerYou.addPoint(gpt, getString(R.string.markerYou), getString(R.string.markerYouDescription));

    }

}
```

And this is how I put multiple markers for places of interest

```
public void putPlacesOfInterest(){
    this.dh = new DataHelper(ShowMap.this);
    List<Pontos> list = this.dh.selectAll();
    for(Pontos p : list){
        markerPlaces.add(new OverlayItem(p.getName().toString(), Long.toString(p.getId()), new GeoPoint(p.getLat(), p.getLng())));
    }
    mMyLocationOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(markerPlaces, new OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongPress(int index, OverlayItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(ShowMap.this, "" + item.mTitle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(int index, OverlayItem item) {
            showplaceDialog(Integer.parseInt(item.mDescription),item.mTitle);
            return true;
        }

    }, mResourceProxy);

    mapView.getOverlays().add(mMyLocationOverlay);
    mapView.invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into the [addProximityAlert()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) function available in the LocationManager class. I am not sure how many listeners you are able to register though.

Your other choice is to do a check on every location update. When your app gets a `onLocationChanged()` callback you can loop through your places of interest, and check to see if they are within 50 meters of the current location. To make this even easier, you can use the `distanceTo()` method in the Location class.

Comment: proximity alert is the way to go.

Comment: I should use `addProximityAlert()` inside `for(Pontos p : list){` right?

Comment: I can't get it working, can you give me an example calling `showplaceDialog()` function? Thanks